# How to print the memory address of a slice in Golang?

Tags: go, slice, memory-address

I have some experience in C and I am totally new to golang.

```
func learnArraySlice() {
  intarr := [5]int{12, 34, 55, 66, 43}
  slice := intarr[:]
  fmt.Printf("the len is %d and cap is %d \n", len(slice), cap(slice))
  fmt.Printf("address of slice 0x%x add of Arr 0x%x \n", &slice, &intarr)
}
```

Now in golang slice is a reference of array which contains the pointer to an array len of slice and cap of slice but this slice will also be allocated in memory and i want to print the address of that memory. But unable to do that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

```
fmt.Printf("address of slice %p add of Arr %p \n", &slice, &intarr)
```

`%p` will print the address.

Answer (score 18):

Slices and their elements are addressable:

```
s := make([]int, 10)
fmt.Printf("Addr of first element: %p\n", &s[0])
fmt.Printf("Addr of slice itself:  %p\n", &s)
```

Comment: I haven't actually looked into the source code, but `fmt.Printf("Addr of first element: %p\n", s)` also work. It kind of makes sense, when you're think about that `fmt.Printf("%v", s)` prints the elements of the underlying array.

Answer (score 5):

For the addresses of the slice underlying array and the array (they are the same in your example),

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    intarr := [5]int{12, 34, 55, 66, 43}
    slice := intarr[:]
    fmt.Printf("the len is %d and cap is %d \n", len(slice), cap(slice))
    fmt.Printf("address of slice %p add of Arr %p\n", &slice[0], &intarr)
}
```

Output:

```
the len is 5 and cap is 5 
address of slice 0x1052f2c0 add of Arr 0x1052f2c0
```

Comment: Why address of slice[0] is equal to address arr, why slice[1] and arr[1] has different address

Comment: It's wrong, it's referencing to the same place, the address of slice is &slice

Answer (score 1):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    intArr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    intSlice := intArr[:]
    fmt.Printf("slice addr= %p, len= %d, cap= %d\n", &intSlice, len(intArr), cap(intArr))
    fmt.Printf("array addr= %p, len= %d, cap= %d\n", &intArr, len(intArr), cap(intArr))
    fmt.Printf("slice first elem addr=%p\n", &intSlice[0])
    fmt.Printf("backend array of slice addr=%p\n", intSlice)
    fmt.Printf("backend array of slice addr=%#v\n", *((*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&intSlice))))
}
```

output:

```
slice addr= 0xc0000a4018, len= 5, cap= 5
array addr= 0xc0000b6000, len= 5, cap= 5
slice first elem addr=0xc0000b6000
backend array of slice addr=0xc0000b6000
backend array of slice addr=reflect.SliceHeader{Data:0xc0000b6000, Len:5, Cap:5}
```