# What memory value of slice pointer means?

Tags: pointers, go

I am trying to understand pointers in go, but I am still a little bit confused, how they work.

I already look at other question on SO: [print the Address of slice in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811138/print-the-address-of-slice-in-golang) , [How do I print the pointer value of a Go object? What does the pointer value mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938612/how-do-i-print-the-pointer-value-of-a-go-object-what-does-the-pointer-value-mea) , but still couldn't wrap my mind around this concept.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    numbers := myNumbers{42}
    println("Pointer to numbers", &numbers)
    numbers.printSlice()
    numbers.printPointer()
}

type myNumbers []int

func (m myNumbers) printSlice() {
    fmt.Printf("printSlice - value of m:  %p \n", m)
    fmt.Printf("printSlice - value of &m: %p\n", &m)
}

func (m *myNumbers) printPointer() {
    fmt.Printf("printPointer - value of m:  %p\n", m)
    fmt.Printf("printPointer - value of &m:  %p\n", &m)
}
```

And output is:

```
Pointer to numbers 0xc42000a060
printSlice - value of m:  0xc420016100 
printSlice - value of &m: 0xc42000a080
printPointer - value of m:  0xc42000a060
printPointer - value of &m:  0xc42000c030
```

As per go documentation in `printSlice`, the first line will print the address of the first element of the array, the second line will print the address of copy of slice header

In `printPointer`, the first line will print the value of the pointer, the second line will print the address of the pointer

In `main` `prinln` prints the same address as the first line of `printPointer`, so does it mean that in `printPointer` I've got a pointer which points to an original pointer?

Are the above assumptions correct?

Comment: The printPointer method is called with address of `numbers` as the receiver argument.  The print statement in main and the first print statement in printPointer print the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numbers` in `main` is a slice, so you can think of it as a struct with three values, ptr to underlying array, length, capacity. When you print `&numbers`, you're printing the address of this struct.

`printPointer` has a pointer receiver, so in `printPointer`, `m` is a pointer to the struct defined in `main`. That's why when you print `m`, you get the same value you printed in `main`. When you print `&m`, you're printing the value of a pointer to a pointer. `&m` is a pointer that points to the receiver of the function, which points to `m` in `main`.

`printSlice` gets a copy of `m`. So when you print `&m`, you print the address of that copy.